# Summer Project - need a GUI (I think?)

Tags: gui

I want to start and finish my first personal project this summer. Basically, I have ADHD, and enjoy using an online planner. However, I have not yet found one that does everything I want, exactly how I want it, so I want to make my own. I want it to be a multiplatform computer application, so I am assuming I need some sort of GUI? Where would I find a GUI that does what I need? Also, what language would be best suited for this task? I am basically a newbie, but I wanted to spend this summer really learning how to apply programming and I thought this project would be a great way to do that. Any tips, advice, etc would be greatly appreciated, as I basically only know backend programming

Answer (score 1):

I've also been thinking to make similar software this summer, but I've confined its focus to mobile, So I've used flutter ( cross-platform app development framework).

Though flutter does support desktop as well, it's quite still more like a baby now.

I would suggest you try pyQT5, which uses QT framework on top of python language. 
You can make desktop apps with a single codebase, for macOS, windows, and Linux as well.

There are various books and tutorials available on udemy and google regarding it. Learning it wouldn't be an issue.

hope that helps :)

Comment: Don't use PyQt5, use Qt for Python (formerly known as PySide2).
That's the official python bindings for Qt5 !
https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python ,  https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python , https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)

> **Web Technologies**
>
> Electron uses Chromium and Node.js so you can build your app with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
>
> **Open Source**
>
> Electron is an open source project maintained by GitHub and an active community of contributors.
>
> **Cross Platform**
>
> Compatible with Mac, Windows, and Linux, Electron apps build and run on three platforms.